# P4v Integration error

Tags: version-control, branch, perforce, integrate

I have created a new branch (N) from one of my code lines (A). Now I am trying to integrate some files from another codeline (B) having the same tree structure into my new branch.

I am using Integrate option from P4v GUI.Source branch is B and target branch N and using a branch spec to accomplish this.

While integrating I am in the workspace which has branch N in its view but branch B is not in view as it resides on another server.

I am continuously getting the following error
**Integration error
 - no target file(s) in branch view**

I have searched on the net and seems a lot of people face this issue but haven't found any solutions. Please help.

Comment: B resides on another server?  Is it mapped in to the server containing A and N as a remote depot?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that B resided on another server and I did not have remote depot mapping on server containing A and N. Adding that mapping resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using P4V, you can easily be misdirected by the GUI. In particular, if you right click somewhere to select "Merge/Integrate...", then the thing you've clicked on is going to be used as the target, EVEN IF YOU USE A BRANCH SPECIFICATION.

I puzzled over something very similar for ages, until I realised that I was clicking on branch B to start the merge, rather than clicking on branch N.

The GUI misdirection is that thing you clicked is originally shown as a target, but when you choose to use a branch specification, then that part of the dialogue disappears. It's still there on the "Filter" tab, but you've already forgotten about it because the GUI took it away...

Comment: it really seem to make a difference where you click, even when you swap target and source in the merge/integrate dialog later (using branch mapping)

Answer (score 1):

I guess its not a remote issues as he is getting the source branch using p4v and can select the source and target to integrate. I would rather suggest to check your workspace client view.

the following error also may come when your Source and the target view of your integration should not be mapped in your workspace which might be missing at present.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem doing merge like the following,

```
p4 merge filename
```

It happened that the file was not in a branch that is created as stream. So it does not have a track of the parent.

To fix this I used the following command. I specified the branch `devel_branch_name` here.

```
p4 merge -b devel_branch_name filename
```

I was sitting in the development branch.

There are [more information here](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/streams_merge.html).